how to add missing binary (eg. ffmpeg) to an aws sagemaker deployment image
I am deploying an AWS image on an AWS sagemaker endpoint. The image is specified as the image_uri in the following code :
def deploy_model(image_uri, model_data, role, endpoint_name, instance_type, env, sagemaker_session, async_inference_config):
    
    """Helper function to create the SageMaker Endpoint resources and return a predictor"""
    
    model = Model(
            image_uri=image_uri, 
              model_data=model_data, 
              role=role,
              env=env
             )
    
    model.deploy(
        initial_instance_count=1,
        instance_type=instance_type,
        endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
        async_inference_config=async_inference_config
        )
    
    predictor = sagemaker.Predictor(
        endpoint_name=endpoint_name, 
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
    )

However one binary that I need (ffmpeg) is not present.
ffmpeg not found
What is the expected procedure to add this binary ?
If it is of any help, the image I am using is :763104351884.dkr.ecr.europe-west-1.amazonaws.com/djl-inference:0.21.0-deepspeed0.8.3-cu117.
EDIT:
I found this documentation about adding custom binaries : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deep-learning-containers/latest/devguide/deep-learning-containers-custom-images.html

As far as I know, you have to build your own image, like the example you shared, and install ffmpeg in it.
